# Proof of $\operatorname{Br}(K) = H^2(G,K^*)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, group-cohomology, brauer-group

The proofs I know of the fact $\operatorname{Br}(K) = H^2(G,K^*)$ ($G= \operatorname{Gal}(K^s/K))$ involve non-abelian group cohomology of $H^1(G,PGL_n(K))$. Are there any nice conceptual proofs which don't non-abelian cohomology in anyway?

Comment: **The** conceptual proof is through nonabelian cohomology. CSAs are forms of matrix algebras, and they are classified by Galois cohomology, nonabelian because the automorphism group of matriz algebras is nonabelian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use crossed product algebras to do this. See the book by Pierce on *Associative Algebras*, for example.

Comment: (Most people would not call this conceptual, I guess. Emmy Noether would tell them to deal with it ;-) It is conceptual in that it is so concrete that you can understand what you are talking about, which is the sinequanon of concepts)